# Assigning the host option for file_get_contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have a little problem here. So I was trying to access a page per `file_get_contents` and using the received data. If I don't add any changes to the normal access options it works "fine" but as soon as I try to add the `host` option for the `stream_context_create` function it displays an error.

So the script:

```
<?php
$opts = stream_context_create(array(
  'http'=> array(
    'method' => 'GET',
    'header'=> 'Host: "battlelog.battlefield.com"',
  )
));
$url = "http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf4/soldier/Feirell/detailedstats/382046730/1/";
echo file_get_contents($url, NULL, $opts);
?>
```

And the error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf4/soldier/Feirell/detailedstats/382046730/1/): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
```

But I need the host option to correctly show the needed content, because some of the content resources is assumed to be on the php server and not on the "battlelog.battlefield.com" server.

So can someone help me to correctly assign this option ?

Comment: Have you seen this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508586/php-stream-context-create-and-http-headers-array-or-string-r-n-at-the-end-c ?

Comment: @BrianKH no I did not but I don't know how this should help me ? He didn't got an error just an empty string back. I got an specific error back.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I got it. You have double-quotes in your Host header, which is not valid. Try this:

```
$opts = stream_context_create(array(
    'http'=> array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'header'=> 'Host: battlelog.battlefield.com',
    )
));
```

Or try dropping the Host header completely. I don't see why it's needed here.

Comment: sadly this does not solve the problem, I got you two sreenshots from Firefox network overview [original page](http://puu.sh/kgKQc/7b02be2353.png) and the [page I posted the source code and also involved you answer](http://puu.sh/kgKRR/951be509cc.png) It shows that it is using the localhost and not the given host :( this also has an impact on the displayed data, I think that a JS is generating a part of it but it does not get loaded correctly.

Comment: I think your javascript is generating a bad URL, since your second screenshot shows that the URL used is localhost (it's not just the Host header). Can you post the code that generates the URL for purista.css incorrectly?

Comment: I also noticed that your second screenshot shows the error is now HTTP 404, not HTTP 400. I think the 400 was caused by the quotes in the Host header, but now you have a different problem that's causing the 404 (the incorrect host name in the URL).

Comment: Yeah I though that the `host` would resolve the problem with the different host. And sorry but I can't show the needed information, because I don't know where it is. The source site is not mine.

Comment: How are you getting the URL? From your PHP, it looks like it's hardcoded in the PHP code, but your browser isn't showing that. I think we need to take a step back and see what the bigger picture is. What is the purpose of your application? Are you trying to scrape the battlelog.battlefield.com site, or are you doing something else? Also, how is your PHP code called to be executed? Are you hitting your site with your browser, and expecting their page to stream to you?

Comment: Also, can you post the relevant HTML that calls purista.css, using "View Source" in your browser? I want to see if it's an absolute URL or relative. I noticed your browser was pointed to localhost, so if it's relative that might be why.

Comment: Ok, so the purpose of this is to read two numbers from this site every 24h, the cronjob invokes this and should put this numbers in a MySQL database. So this process should never meet client side. The CSS is not relevant, it was just to point out that it is still using the localhost as source. [How the source looks like](http://puu.sh/kgMT0/5b724b221c.jpg) and [how the current page displays it](http://puu.sh/kgMUL/b0cd661171.jpg). In the final state it is not needed to actually display the site just getting the correct html from the server, and generating the data per JS.

Comment: Why do you use stream_context_create()? I would expect file_get_contents() would be sufficient on its own for a cron job.

Comment: sadly it just shows the posted content, like an JS is needed to generate the data. I though I might get it running when I use stream_context_create

Comment: If they use AJAX to get the data, you will need to do that as well. You will need to see how they are getting the data to the browser and do as they do, but in PHP instead of JS.

Comment: Well there are around 150'000 lines of JS ... do you have an idea to find the source of the generating part.

Comment: Sorry, I think you'll need to find/hire someone who works with JS to do that.

Comment: Mh ok well I actually found another solution to my problem, so thank you for you help and support :)